# Identify NULL values in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know we can use nil for validating null values in objective c. I"ve been trying to use it but the programe crashes everytime.

THis is what I get in service as response

```
2013-12-16 12:45:32.867 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 0
2013-12-16 12:45:32.868 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] <null>
2013-12-16 12:45:32.868 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] <null>
2013-12-16 12:45:32.868 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] <null>
2013-12-16 12:45:32.868 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] <null>
2013-12-16 12:45:32.869 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 70
2013-12-16 12:45:32.869 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 130
2013-12-16 12:45:32.869 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 0
2013-12-16 12:45:32.869 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 80
2013-12-16 12:45:32.869 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 50.5
2013-12-16 12:45:32.869 Pizza to Go[1857:a0b] 10
```

I tried this first and crashed

```
if([[result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] isEqualToString:@"<null>"]){
    orderHead.price = 0;
}else{
    orderHead.price = [[result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] doubleValue];
}
```

then this also crashed.

```
if([result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] == nil){
    orderHead.price = 0;
}else{
    orderHead.price = [[result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] doubleValue];
}
```

This is from the error log

```
-[NSNull doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20af068
2013-12-16 12:55:19.017 Pizza to Go[2083:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20af068'
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Some help apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation collections can only contain objects types (`NSObject` subclasses). As such, in order to represent nil we use `+[NSNull null]`. It just so happens that `NSNull`'s implementation of `-description` returns `<null>` and that's what you're seeing in the console.

Try comparing the result of `-objectForKey` to `[NSNull null]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary` accepts `[NSNull null]` to indicate a null entry.

Edit: But yes, when just comparing values

```
if([result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"]){
    orderHead.price = 0;
}else{
    orderHead.price = [[result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] doubleValue];
}
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
   if ([[result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
   {
      orderHead.price = 0;
   }
```

Comment: The class comparison is overkill here. `+null` is implemented as a singleton and it will always satisfy simple pointer comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(![result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"]){
    orderHead.price = 0;
}else{
    orderHead.price = [[result[i] objectForKey:@"ordertotalprice"] doubleValue];
}
```